# IE8 Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, tabs, addeventlistener, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm receiving complaints from IE8 users (I know) that they are unable to open an accordion tab.

They are presented with the following error:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

```
        document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );
        window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false );
        }
       }
      return readyList.promise( obj );
    };
 jQuery.ready.promise();
```

I'm currently using jquery 2.1.3

This error also appears again on the following script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('txt1').addEventListener('change', function () {
var style = this.value == 'GP Practice' ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('txtpcode').style.display = style;
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Is there away to get this to work under IE8 as I know addEventListener isnt supported.

Comment: Microsoft no longer produce security fixes for IE8. Encourage people to upgrade to a modern browser instead of bloating your site to support IE8.

Comment: IE8 holds 0.78% of the browser marketshare Worldwild (IE9 - 0.51%) (IE10 0.47%) **anything less then 1% is not worth spending time on**

Comment: I completely agree with the both of you.

Comment: @Endless—that's not good customer service, particularly when the fix is really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Under IE8 you need to use `attachEvent`. With pure javascript you need to detect <strike>the browser of the user</strike> support and use `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`.

But I suggest you to use [**JQuery**](https://jquery.com/)'s `on()` function. It contains the logic and will work in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

attached = target.attachEvent(eventNameWithOn, callback)

**Target**

The DOM element to listen for the event on

**eventNameWithOn**

The name of the event to listen for, prefixed with "on", as if it were an event handler attribute. For example, you would use "onclick" to listen for the click event.

**callback**

Callback function to call when the event is triggered on this target. The function will be called with no arguments, and with the this reference set to the window object.
attached
Boolean indicating whether the event handler was successfully attached.

Comment: *attachEvent* does not set *this* in the listener, which the OP's code infers. There are many examples of how to emulate *addEventListener* with *attachEvent*.